# Invalid Parameter Value: AWS Environment named *** is in an invalid state for this operation. Must be Ready

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I get a message when I am trying to deploy my php app on EC2 using Elastic Beanstalk.

`Environment named *** is in an invalid state for this operation. Must be Ready.`

I am unable to deploy. The server status is running, Environment Health is OK and no warnings.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Duplicate of https://serverfault.com/questions/720039

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is the same case for you but I got the same error when I was under the impression my environment was healthy - I figured out my issue by clicking on "Show all" in the Recent events section, at which point the culprit error logs were displayed.

Answer (score 1):

You should open the "Show all", choose warnings or errors.
Try to detect the service that is the root cause and take the appropriate action.
In my case, it was an EC2 instance that somehow hasn't passed the status check. My solution was to restart the instance and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Actions -> Rebuild Environment. That solved the problem for me. Hope it helps! [AWS Elasticbeanstalk Menu: Actions -> Rebuild](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IryU9.png)